# indexOfObject vs. indexOfObjectIdenticalTo

Tags: objective-c, nsarray

What is the difference between these two NSArray methods?

Answer (score 72, accepted):

[`indexOfObjectIdenticalTo`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/NSArray.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSArray/indexOfObjectIdenticalTo:) checks for the exact same `id` (same address).  [`indexOfObject`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/NSArray.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSArray/indexOfObject:) checks that [`isEqual:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Protocols/NSObject_Protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/NSObject/isEqual:) returns `YES`.

Comment: Also note that `indexOfObjectIdenticalTo:` is many orders of magnitude faster than `indexOfObject:`. Although neither is particularly fast. If you want high performance you should consider using `NSSet`

Answer (score 18):

The first uses `isEqual:` to find a matching object, while the second looks for the same object (i.e., the object at the same memory location).

Comment: Any way to make it use isEqualToString: instead?

Comment: @SantaClaus: It already does. `isEqual:` and `isEqualToString:` behave identically when you pass an `NSString *`. The only differences between the two are a slight performance advantage and static type checking provided by `isEqualToString:`, which is irrelevant in the context of `indexOfObject:`.

Comment: @MarceloCantos Hmmm. I have an issue then. :)

Comment: @MarceloCantos I'll just make a new question eventually

Comment: It's funny how the two answers contradict each other. You say the first checks for equal, while the other guys says the other one checks for the equal function instead of id.

Comment: @GillesLesire: Actually, they're both the same. They just present the cases in a different order.

Comment: You are right. Skimmed through the answers too fast.

Answer (score 2):

`indexOfObjectIdenticalTo` is far more faster than `indexOfObject` but it uses pointer comparison `==` instead of calling `isEqual:`

**If you are searching for a pointer match, always use `indexOfObjectIdenticalTo`** to get peak performance