# Most efficient way to find out if an object is already in an NSMutableArray?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsmutablearray

I just want to know if an object is in an array or not.

So I can use:

```
- (BOOL)containsObject:(id)anObj
```

But it would send -isEqual to every object in the array. Bad when there are thousands of them.

And then there is:

```
- (NSUInteger)indexOfObjectIdenticalTo:(id)anObject
```

which seems to only compare the memory addresses. I think this is faster. But a bit nasty to use, of course. One would have to check for NSNotFound.

Is -indexOfObjectIdenticalTo really the best option?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you really need this often, you can create an instance method by category:

```
@interface NSArray (MONStuff)
- (BOOL)mon_containsObject:(id)object;
@end


@implementation NSArray (MONStuff)

- (BOOL)mon_containsObject:(id)object {
  return NSNotFound != [self indexOfObjectIdenticalTo:arg];
}

@end
```

or these's also `CFArrayContainsValue`.

a simple function would also suffice.

Comment: A good simplification of the interface.  However, i would name it mon_containsObjectIdenticalTo: to mirror the indexOfObject: indexOfObjectIdenticalTo: pair.

Answer (score 2):

> But a bit nasty to use

Why?  It seems to me that

```
if ([array indexOfObjectIdenticalTo: foo] != NSNotFound)
{
    // do what you need
}
```

is not much more nasty than

```
if ([array containsObject: foo])
{
    // do what you need
}
```

Which one you choose depends on what equality semantics you use.  You almost certainly want to use `-containsObject:` for arrays containing `NSString`s or `NSNumber`s because `-isEqual:` gives the correct equality semantics.

Both methods, by the way are *O(n)* which is where the real performance problem is.  If the idea of a linear search is a problem, consider a different data structure e.g. based on NSDictionary.

Comment: Like you can see yourself the second one is a lot shorter and has less instructions. So yes, comparing to NSNotFound is somewhat nasty :=)

Comment: +1 for the O(n) thing. Yes this would suck. Making use of the powerful hash function of dictionaries is a good idea. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

As per your explaining and comparison `indexOfObjectIdenticalTo` seems me the first choice to use..

Here is one more SO post ..

[indexOfObject vs. indexOfObjectIdenticalTo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3167849/indexofobject-vs-indexofobjectidenticalto)

Answer (score 1):

If possible (for example if sorting order is irrelevant) you could use an NSDictionary instead, with your object as keys and values of `[NSNull null]`. Note that the objects get copied when used as keys ! Your objects would need to implement the `- (NSUInteger)hash` method.

Also see the excellent [NSArray or NSSet, NSDictionary or NSMapTable](http://cocoawithlove.com/2008/08/nsarray-or-nsset-nsdictionary-or.html) analysis from Matt Gallagher.