# Unable to get an indexvalue of an object in nsmutablearray in iphone

Tags: iphone, nsarray

in my application at one place I have to get the index value of a particular object. For this I coded in this manner as shown below.

```
NSString *a=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",[imagesdmobject.proofID intValue]];
NSLog(@"a value is %@",a);
```

Here a value is 56
Now I have to get the index of 56 from `appdelegate.projectTitlesProofIDArray`.

```
int value=[appdelegate.projectTitlesProofIDArray indexOfObjectIdenticalTo:a];
```

data in `appdelegate.projectTitlesProofIDArray` is :

41,
    34,
    35,
    64,
    45,
    1,
    67,
    75,
    76,
    77,
    78,
    79,
    80,
    81,
    82,
    83,
    85,
    68,
    86,
    87,
    88,
    89,
    90,
    92,
    69,
    95,
    97,
    98,
    100,
    101,
    70,
    71,
    72,
    73,
    74,
    39,
    37,
    109,
    108,
    110,
    38,
    91,
    93,
    94,
    36,
    96,
    99,
    102,
    103,
    104,
    105,
    106,
    107,
    65,
    66,
    40,
    46,
    47,
    48,
    49,
    50,
    52,
    53,
    54,
    60,
    61,
    62,
    32,
    55,
    56,
    57,
    58,
    59,
    42,
    43,
    44,
    63,
    47,
    48,
    41,
    34,
    35,
    64,
    1,
    91,
    93,
    94,
    36,
    96,
    99,
    102,
    103,
    104,
    105,
    106,
    107,
    65,
    66,
    40,
    60,
    61,
    62,
    32,
    55,
    56,
    57,
    58,
    59,
    54,
    34,
    35,
    41,
    34,
    35,
    64,
    67,
    75,
    76,
    77,
    78,
    79,
    80,
    81,
    82,
    83,
    85,
    68,
    86,
    87,
    88,
    89,
    90,
    92,
    69,
    95,
    97,
    98,
    100,
    101,
    70,
    71,
    72,
    73,
    74,
    39,
    37,
    109,
    108,
    110,
    38,
    91,
    93,
    94,
    36,
    96,
    99,
    102,
    103,
    104,
    105,
    106,
    107,
    65,
    66,
    40,
    46,
    47,
    48,
    49,
    50,
    52,
    53,
    54,
    41,
    34,
    35,
    64,
    45,
    1,
    67,
    75,
    76,
    77,
    78,
    79,
    80,
    81,
    82,
    83,
    85,
    68,
    86,
    87,
    88,
    89,
    90,
    92,
    69,
    95,
    97,
    98,
    100,
    101,
    70,
    71,
    72,
    73,
    74,
    39,
    37,
    109,
    108,
    110,
    38,
    91,
    93,
    94,
    36,
    96,
    99,
    102,
    103,
    104,
    105,
    106,
    107,
    65,
    66,
    40,
    46,
    47,
    48,
    49,
    50,
    52,
    53,
    54,
    60,
    61,
    62,
    32,
    55,
    56,
    57,
    58,
    59,
    42,
    43,
    44,
    47,
    34,
    35,
    39,
    37,
    109,
    108,
    110,
    38,
    46,
    47,
    48,
    49,
    50,
    52,
    53,
    54,
    42,
    43,
    44,
    41,
    34,
    35,
    64,
    45,
    1,
    67,
    75,
    76,
    77,
    78,
    79,
    80,
    81,
    83,
    85,
    68,
    86,
    87,
    88,
    89,
    90,
    92,
    69,
    95,
    97,
    98,
    100,
    70,
    71,
    73,
    74,
    39,
    37,
    109,
    108,
    110,
    38,
    91,
    94,
    36,
    96,
    99,
    102,
    103,
    104,
    105,
    106,
    107,
    65,
    66,
    40,
    46,
    47,
    48,
    49,
    50,
    52,
    54,
    60,
    61,
    62,
    32,
    55,
    56,
    57,
    58,
    59,
    42,
    43,
    63,
    41,
    34,
    35,
    64,
    45,
    1,
    67,
    75,
    76,
    77,
    78,
    79,
    80,
    81,
    82,
    83,
    85,
    68,
    86,
    87,
    88,
    89,
    90,
    92,
    69,
    95,
    97,
    98,
    100,
    101,
    70,
    71,
    72,
    73,
    74,
    39,
    37,
    109,
    108,
    110,
    38,
    91,
    93,
    94,
    36,
    96,
    99,
    102,
    103,
    104,
    105,
    106,
    107,
    65,
    66,
    40,
    46,
    47,
    48,
    49,
    50,
    52,
    53,
    54,
    60,
    61,
    62,
    32,
    55,
    56,
    57,
    58,
    59,
    42,
    43,
    44,
    63,
    41,
    34,
    35,
    64,
    45,
    1,
    67,
    75,
    76,
    77,
    78,
    79,
    80,
    81,
    82,
    83,
    85,
    68,
    86,
    87,
    88,
    89,
    90,
    92,
    69,
    95,
    97,
    98,
    100,
    101,
    70,
    71,
    72,
    73,
    74,
    39,
    37,
    109,
    108,
    110,
    38,
    91,
    93,
    94,
    36,
    96,
    99,
    102,
    103,
    104,
    105,
    106,
    107,
    65,
    66,
    40,
    46,
    47,
    48,
    49,
    50,
    52,
    53,
    54,
    60,
    61,
    62,
    32,
    55,
    56,
    57,
    58,
    59,
    42,
    43,
    44,
    63,
    46

56 is there, but I am getting the incorrect value as 2147483647.

Please help me in this issue. I am stuck at this place.

Comment: May be your array contains spaces in strings

Comment: 2147483647 is NSNotFound - not a garbage value.

Comment: Use indexOfObject: instead of indexOfObjectIdenticalTo: (see http://stackoverflow.com/q/3167849/1331515) and make sure you compare string to string or number to number.

Answer (score 0):

You need to do this:-

Suppose you array contains:-

```
[array addObject:@"1"];
[array addObject:@"2"];
[array addObject:@"3"];
[array addObject:@"4"];
[array addObject:@"5"];
[array addObject:@"6"];
```

Now you need to find the index of object 5

```
if([array containsObject:@"5"])
{
int index=[array indexOfObject:@"5"];
}
```

Comment: hi gypsa thanks a lot. even i wrote in this manner as below                 int value=[appdelegate.projectTitlesProofIDArray indexOfObject:@"56"];
that time also i am getting the garbade value.

Comment: does your ppdelegate.projectTitlesProofIDArray  contains sring or some other data type because @"56" means it is nsstring, show how are you adding data in array.

Comment: you need to post the code of how are you adding data in array.

Comment: hi gypsa i wrote the in this manner   if([appdelegate.projectTitlesProofIDArray containsObject:a])
                {
                    
                    
                    int value=[appdelegate.projectTitlesProofIDArray indexOfObject:a];

                    NSLog(@"tag value is %d",value);

                }
                
even i am not getting. my question is 56 is there in my array then why i am not getting please help me.

Comment: You are  understanding my point, the code for extracting index is fine, there is something either with the data type difference or when you are adding data in array.Thats why I asked you to post code of how are you adding data in array.

Comment: hi gypsa ok fine i will post.

Comment: hi got the output. the modifications what i did is         NSString *proofstr=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",dmobject.proofID];
[appdelegate.projectTitlesProofIDArray addObject:proofstr]; in this manner i am adding the data in array. here dmobject.proofid is nsstring object but the data what i am getting from the server this proof id is int due to that its happen. thanks